# Error: When i minimize Internet Explorer which is running the automated WebDriver Code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written the `Selenium webdriver java code` to automate the test and its working fine. But I have lot of data input to test my web and it takes time. So when i minimize the IE to do some other task while it is running the automation, it is throwing error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Selenium `WebDriver` is trying to simulate "real" users interaction with the webpage. If a person can't click on a button not currently displayed, neither can Selenium.

`ElementNotVisibleException` occurs when the element you want to interact with is not displayed. When you minimize the browser some of the elements are no longer visible, even though they where in maximized window.

You can add scroll using `moveToElement()` from [Actions class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-int-int-) every time you want to perform any action (I don't recommend it, you increase significantly the chance for errors), or find another hardware solution, like plugging in another screen, run the test on another computer etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, the Internet Explorer WebDriver is very oversensitive when it comes to disturbances from a real user while running test cases. It's better to not touch anything at all. ;-)

Try Chrome! This is much more robust and also faster.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium script runs as a simulator. You cannot do another work when script is running. Chrome is fast but while running script in chrome you can not do other task like any other browser. If you minimize window, you will get exception "ElementNotVisible".